# DataTable item selection on custom input checkbox class name

Tags: javascript, datatables

i am using DataTables library to manage some tables data. Currently datatable items get selected as per click on anywhere of row. But my goal is row will be selected by input check class named- "checkItem". Is it possible with DataTables library? Note: I already tried to replace className: 'select-checkbox' with className: 'checkItem' but no luck. Please help

Javascript:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.5/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.5/css/select.dataTables.min.css">


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'multi',
            //selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
} );

</script>
```

Html:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" class="checkItem" name="checkItem" value="1" /></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" class="checkItem" name="checkItem" value="1" /></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" class="checkItem" name="checkItem" value="2" /></td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" class="checkItem" name="checkItem" value="3" /></td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" class="checkItem" name="checkItem" value="4" /></td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" class="checkItem" name="checkItem" value="5" /></td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent of the clicked checkbox and then add class to the element. Here is the [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/Ishmam/vbzspua9/19/)

```
<table width="100%" id="example">
  <thead style="background:#C0C0C0;">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5">first headline</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> check box </th>
      <th style="padding-left: 15px;"> Id </th>
      <th> Product Name </th>
      <th> Total Events </th>
      <th> Total Revenue </th>
      <th> Rental Time </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectrow"></td>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>4804</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectrow"></td>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>9608</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
<style>
  .select-checkbox {
    background: blue;
  }

</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  $('.selectrow').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).parent().parent().hasClass('select-checkbox')) {
      $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('select-checkbox');
    } else {
      table.$('tr.select-checkbox').removeClass('select-checkbox');
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass('select-checkbox');
    }
  });
});
```